# change mp4 file size to a specific size

Tags: file, video, mp4

I have a mp4 video file, with size 219.6 kB (219,643 bytes).

I need to change the video file size to a specific size, say 275.8 kB (275,791 bytes). It doesn't have to be a larger size than before, it could also be changed to a smaller size.

How can I make this work? (I have both windows/ubuntu environments)

Comment: What does it mean to "change the size" of a video file? Do you want to change its length, quality, both, or neither?

Comment: Change the file size!

Comment: But how? You can't make the file smaller without removing some of its contents. Something has to give.

Comment: My question above is asking about how to make this happen.